# Why is XCode giving me an "Incomplete Implementation" warning?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings, implementation

I am doing an iTunes U course on iPhone app programming, and have followed the instructions to the letter up to this point.  It is a simple card-matching game, but XCode keeps telling me that I am not fully implementing my Card class.

Card.h

```
//
//  Card.h
//  Matchismo
//
//  Created by Jacob Peroutek on 6/14/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 JPeroutek. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Card : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *contents;
@property (nonatomic, getter=faceUp) BOOL faceUp;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isUnplayable) BOOL unplayable;

- (int) match:(NSArray *)otherCards;

@end
```

and this is my Card.m .  It shows a little yellow triangle warning sign beside it and says "Incomplete Implementation"

Card.m

```
//
//  Card.m
//  Matchismo
//
//  Created by Jacob Peroutek on 6/14/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 JPeroutek. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Card.h"

@implementation Card

- (int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards
{
    int score = 0;
    for (Card *card in otherCards)
    {
        if([card.contents isEqualToString:self.contents])
        {
            score = 1;
        }
    }
    return score;
}

@end
```

This is my first question on this site, so if I did something wrong, please tell me.

EDIT:
I typed in

```
@synthesize contents;
@synthesize faceUp;
@synthesize unplayable;
```

into my Card.m after the @implementation, and it still gives me the same warning.

Comment: Depending on your Xcode version and target, you might need to use `@synthesize` for your properties.

Comment: which is your xcode version?

Comment: My version is version 4.6.3.

Comment: If you expand the warning in the Issue Navigator (hit ⌘-4), it will tell you the method the compiler is expecting. There's also a fuller display in the Build Log -- ⌘-7 to see that.

Comment: It says method definition for "match:" not found, even though I'm pretty sure I put the method in there right.

Comment: Xcode sometimes gets stuck. Try deleting derived data.

Comment: what does that mean. sorry, i am pretty new to this.

Comment: @Kreiri, you were right, deleted the derived data and it worked.  Any idea how to make it so that I do not have to do that?  And why does it do that?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that.  There is a bug in Xcode dependency engine that causes this failure.

Comment: Ok, thank you all.  Do I have to click something to say that the question is resolved?

Comment: Encourage @Kreiri to post an answer, which you then can accept, and that will mark this question as resolved. If Kreiri doesn't get around to that within a few days, then go ahead and post your own answer, giving Kreiri credit for pointing you in the right direction, and then you can accept your own answer. But give Kreiri a chance to post an answer first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode sometimes gets stuck. Try deleting derived data.